# How to replace all characters in a Java string with stars

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all the characters in a Java String with `*` character. So it shouldn't matter what character it is, it should be replaced with a `*`.

I know there are heaps of examples there on internet but have not one that replaces every character and I have tried myself but no success.

Comment: every character including spaces?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### Java 11 and later

```
str = "*".repeat(str.length());
```

**Note:** This replaces newlines `\n` with `*`. If you want to preserve `\n`, see solution below.

### Java 10 and earlier

```
str = str.replaceAll(".", "*");
```

This *preserves* newlines.

To replace newlines with `*` as well in Java 10 and earlier, you can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?s).", "*");
```

The `(?s)` doesn't match anything but activates [`DOTALL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode which makes `.` also match `\n`.

Comment: Note that Sonar will warn with the Java 10 and earlier solution, because of squid:S2639.
Rather use a Guava or Commons-lang solution as explained in the other solution.

Comment: "Don't use `.` as regular expression, because you probably meant something else"? ([source](https://github.com/joansmith/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S2639.html)) Quite ridiculous if you ask me.

Comment: Hey, I am but the messenger . On the other hand, matching everything to get a masked string if the same length is arguably an uncommon usage and a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Depends what you ootimize for. If you're after conciseness and readability I'd say it's the best solution.

Answer (score 19):

Don't use regex at all, count the String length, and return the according number of stars.

**Plain Java < 8 Version:**

```
int len = str.length();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
for(int i = =; i < len; i++){
    sb.append('*');
}
return sb.toString();
```

**Plain Java >= 8 Version:**

```
int len = str.length();
return IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> "*").collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**Using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):**

```
return Strings.repeat("*", str.length());
// OR
return CharMatcher.ANY.replaceFrom(str, '*');
```

**Using [Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):**

```
return StringUtils.repeat("*", str.length());
```

Comment: I think it should be "You don't need regex at all" rather than "Don't use regex at all". The latter suggests regex is a wrong solution.

Comment: @taurelas for this problem, it IS the wrong solution. All you need for this problem is the string's length.

Comment: From Java 11 onwards, there's a `repeat` method in the `String` class, so this will be `"*".repeat(str.length())` without the need for any non-JDK library.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println("foobar".replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public String allStar(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        sb.append('*');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How abt creating a new string with the number of * = number of last string char?

```
StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++ ) {
    bf.append('*');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be other faster/better ways to do it, but you could just use a string buffer and a for-loop:

```
public String stringToAsterisk(String input) {
    if (input == null) return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If your application is single threaded, you can use StringBuilder instead, but it's not thread safe.

I am not sure if this might be any faster:

```
public String stringToAsterisk(String input) {
    if (input == null) return "";

    int length = input.length();
    char[] chars = new char[length];
    while (length > 0) chars[--length] = "*";
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any external library and without your own loop, you can do:

```
String input = "Hello";
char[] ca = new char[input.length()];
Arrays.fill(ca, '*');
String output = new String(ca);
```

BTW, both `Arrays.fill()` and `String(char [])` are really fast.

Answer (score 0):

## Recursive method

```
String nCopies(String s, int n) {
    return n == 1 ? s.replaceFirst(".$", "") : nCopies(s + s, --n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "Hello World";
    System.out.println( text.replaceAll( "[A-Za-z0-9]", "*" ) );
```

output : ***** *****

Comment: If the string has special characters like & $ -, it won't work well