# How to replace a string with a symbol of the same length

Tags: java, string

I'm creating a censor, but I'm not sure how I'd replace the length of a word with the symbol *

This is what I have so far

```
package com.rs.game.player.content;

public class CensorHandler {

    private String cuss = "test";

    public boolean checkFilter(String passage) {
        if(passage.toLowerCase().contains(cuss)) 
           return true;
        return false;
    }

    public String replaceWord(String passage) {
        if(checkFilter(passage)) {
           passage.replaceAll(cuss, "*");

        }
        return passage;
    }

}
```

Obviously this will replace the string cuss with just *

```
 passage.replaceAll(cuss, "*");
```

but I want it to replace every letter of the string cuss with *
I'm not sure exactly how to do this though.. I have a feeling I'm going to end up hitting myself in the face for not being able to figure this out.

SO, if the string cuss is test.
test would be replaced by * * * *(ignore spacing)

If the the string cuss is apple
apple would be replaced by * * * * *(ignore spacing)

Comment: Define *"letter"*. Btw `replaceAll` uses a regular expression.

Comment: You mean *"word replacing"*?

Comment: Or the old-fashion way = https://ideone.com/eO4Gks

Comment: A regular expression will do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318359/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-java-string-with-stars

Comment: This is going to lead to [clbuttic censorship failures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S****horpe_problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
passage.replaceAll(cuss, "*");
```

Does absolutely **nothing** because it returns a `String`, which you aren't even using. You have to do:

```
passage = passage.replaceAll(cuss, "*");
```

But considering you want to replace the cuss word with the same length of symbols, perhaps you can try something like:

```
char[] symbols = new char[cuss.length()];
Arrays.fill(symbols, '*');
passage = passage.replaceAll(cuss, new String(symbols));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to replace every letter of the string cuss with *

To replace every character you can do

```
String cussStar = cuss.replaceAll(".", "*");
```