# Remove special character from address using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression,
I want to remove special character from address with spaces(" "), but if special character occurs in between words then remove with no spaces ("").

Example:

> Mr. RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1-7-59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAP[ET AP INDIA

Here,

1) - will be remove by " "

2) . will be remove by " "

But 
3) [ will be remove by ""

Means output something similar to:

> Mr RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1 7 59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAPET AP INDIA

Thanks In advance.

Comment: you will have to do 2 `.replace()` since you want to have 2 different chars as replacement. this regex is for - & . : `\\.|\\-` and for the 2nd use `[`. so your replaces will look like this: `string = string.replace("\\.|\\-"," ").replace("[","");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all characters in a Java string with stars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318359/how-to-replace-all-characters-in-a-java-string-with-stars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str="Mr. RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1-7-59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAP[ET AP INDIA";
str=str.replaceAll("\\.|\\-"," ").replace("[","");;
System.out.println(str);
```

results in this output:
Mr  RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1 7 59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAPET AP INDIA

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()` :

1) & 2) `.replace("\(\\.|-\)+"," ")`
3) `.replace("[","")`

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do 2 `replaceAll()`. One for 1) and 2) and a separate one for 3) and all other potential special characters. This example will give you the expected output from your question

```
String s = "Mr. RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1-7-59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAP[ET AP INDIA";
s = s.replaceAll("[\\\\.-]+", " ");
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s:]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

String yourString="Mr. RAHIMATH BEGH MD H NO 1-7-59 KUMMARI BAZAR SURYAP[ET AP INDIA";

yourString=yourString.replaceAll("\.|\-"," "); //this replace "." and "-" with spaces .

yourString=yourString.replace("[",""); //replace [ with ""

hope it helps :)